# How to get tkinter Entry widgets to auto-update with values from an incoming signal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

On a Raspberry Pi 3b using Python 3.6.2, I'm trying to create a GUI in tkinter that takes voltage inputs from an Adafruit ADS1115 and then displays them 'live' by updating tkinter entry widgets in a read only state. The ADS1115 already converts the signal from analog to digital and I can get them to be displayed in the entry, but those only appear when I start the script. I can't write code to display those converted values at a rate of 1 second. I've tried to use a while loop which caused the code to hang up on the while loop. I've also tried to use threading, but can not figure it out.

How would I be able to get my program to take these values and update the text in the entry at regular intervals?

Here is a sample of my code it is one of the classes, let me know if you like more of it:

```
class DataExtractor(ttk.Frame):    
def __init__(self, parent):
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, padding="10 10 10 10")
    self.parent = parent
    import threading # tried it here

    global x1
    x1 = tk.DoubleVar()
    global y1
    y1 = tk.DoubleVar()
    global x2
    x2 = tk.DoubleVar()
    global y2
    y2 = tk.DoubleVar()

    global Ix1
    Ix1 = tk.DoubleVar()
    global Iy1
    Iy1 = tk.DoubleVar()
    global Ix2
    Ix2 = tk.DoubleVar()
    global Iy2
    Iy2 = tk.DoubleVar()


    self.initComponents()        
    root.after(1000, self.update_data)

def initComponents(self):

    # title
    ttk.Label(self, text="Hofstra AMB Health Monitoring GUI").grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)

        # left side
    ttk.Label(self, text="x1:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E)
    global one
    one = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=x1, state="readonly").grid(column=1, row=1)
    ttk.Label(self, text="micron").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    global two
    ttk.Label(self, text="y1:").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    two = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=y1, state="readonly").grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5, pady=3)
    ttk.Label(self, text="micron").grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    global three
    ttk.Label(self, text="x2:").grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    three = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=x2, state="readonly").grid(column=1, row=3, padx=5, pady=3)
    ttk.Label(self, text="micron").grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    global four
    ttk.Label(self, text="y2:").grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    four = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=y2, state="readonly").grid(column=1, row=4, padx=5, pady=3)
    ttk.Label(self, text="micron").grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    # right side
    global five
    ttk.Label(self, text="Ix1:").grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    five = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=Ix1, state="readonly").grid(column=5, row=1, padx=5, pady=3)
    ttk.Label(self, text="A").grid(column=6, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    global six
    ttk.Label(self, text="Iy1:").grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    six = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=Iy1, state="readonly").grid(column=5, row=2, padx=5, pady=3)
    ttk.Label(self, text="A").grid(column=6, row=2, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    global seven
    ttk.Label(self, text="Ix2:").grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    seven = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=Ix2, state="readonly").grid(column=5, row=3, padx=5, pady=3)
    ttk.Label(self, text="A").grid(column=6, row=3, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    global eight
    ttk.Label(self, text="Iy2:").grid(column=4, row=4, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)
    eight = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=Iy2, state="readonly").grid(column=5, row=4, padx=5, pady=3)
    ttk.Label(self, text="A").grid(column=6, row=4, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=3)


def update_data(self): # just tried this 30 minutes ago but having issue
    import time
    import Adafruit_ADS1x15
    adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
    GAIN = 1

    self.set_text_one()

    def set_text_one(text):
        one.delete(0,END)
        one.insert(0,text)
        return


    set_text(adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN, data_rate=128))# adc read here is how i read the from the chip converting analog to digital



    x1.set(adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN, data_rate=128))
    one.configure(textvariable=x1)
    y1.set(adc.read_adc(1, gain=GAIN, data_rate=128))
    x2.set(adc.read_adc(2, gain=GAIN, data_rate=128))
    y2.set(adc.read_adc(3, gain=GAIN, data_rate=128))


    self.Ix1 = tk.DoubleVar()
    self.Iy1 = tk.DoubleVar()
    self.Ix2 = tk.DoubleVar()
    self.Iy2 = tk.DoubleVar()

    root.after(1000, self.update_data)
```

Please feel free to update the title so it is more correct.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What happens when you run this code? It looks like it's calling `update_data` once a second. What do you need it to do that it's not already doing?

Comment: instead of calling global on several lines just call it once at the first line of the function and separate the variable names with a comma. `global one, two, three, four` and so on. Also all imports should go at the start/top of your program.

Comment: Also you indention is off and you done need global in a class. You should use class attributes instead.

Comment: @ Bryan Thank for the response! When I run the code, everything works except for the auto updating thing where I'm trying to get some numbers that are being taken from the sensor I am using to display to a read only entry field. Is there anything more I could elaborate on? 
Also, Sierra Mountain Tech, thank you for the suggestions I will do that!